# Set a default value in a decimal column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do you set a default value in a decimal column in Rails? I've tried both the following, using Rails 3 and Postgresql, but after each one the console tells me the default values are still `nil`. If I set the value from the console, there's no problem, but it doesn't seem to work in the migration.

```
#Attempt 1
add_column :providers, :commission, :decimal, :precision=>6,:scale=>4,:default=>0.1
```

and

```
#Attempt 2
add_column :providers, :commission, :decimal, :precision=>6,:scale=>4,:default=>BigDecimal("0.1")
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

It turns out I also need to set :null=>false

The following code worked:

```
add_column :providers, :commission, :decimal, :precision=>6,:scale=>4,:default=>0.1, :null => false
```

Comment: Note that the defaults are added by editing the migration once it's been generated - not as part of the command line to initially generate the migration.