# Entity Framework Migrations: convert decimal? to decimal with default value for nulls

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I get `SqlCeException ... The column cannot contain null values. [ Column name = Subtotal`
when I run the following Entity Framework migration.

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("BuildingOrders", "Subtotal",
        c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
}
```

Is this the right way to set the default value? It seems too easy :)

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("BuildingOrders", "Subtotal",
        c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2, defaultValue: 0));
}
```

I tried this after seeing a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287233/set-a-default-value-in-a-decimal-column) question for ruby on rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work this way. You set default value in database but it is not used. You cannot define your property as nullable in class when mapped column is not nullable. Default value in database is applied only if you don't insert any value into that column but EF always inserts value to all columns which are not database generated (in turn values for database generated columns cannot be defined in the application) so in this case you defined your property as nullable and EF inserts null explicitly => exception.

Comment: Ok, I will write a method to convert any nulls to 0.00 - thank you